# multiple words break on absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

I'm building out a tooltip feature for our site, it's what should be a simple highlight over an icon image and some text appears next to it. the problem I'm having is the words that should be inside of that tooltip bubble breaks into a new line for each. when the code is on its own it works fine.

```
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; }
li { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #000; color: #fff; position: relative; }
li:hover { background: #eee; color: #000; }
li:hover #z { display: block; }
#z { position: absolute; left: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange; color: #fff; display: none; }

<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="z">
            some word that shouldn't break
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emqLnmo8/1/

Comment: If you want the whole content as one line without breaking at all, then use the `white-space` property with value `pre` (or another value, if one of the possible choices comes closer to achieving what exactly you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` to stop the words from wrapping.

So with your example: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emqLnmo8/2/)**.